# How do i make value of env variable MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD dynamic in this yaml file and i want to pass this value at run time when i create pod

Tags: kubernetes

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: myapp-pod
  labels:
    app: myapp
spec:
  containers:
  - name: myapp-container
    image: mysql:8.0
    env:
    - name: MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD
      value: root
```

Comment: You can create a `Secret`, and populate the environment variable from that secret.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a secret for storing that value and use that secret as env in the pod.

https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/inject-data-application/distribute-credentials-secure/#define-container-environment-variables-using-secret-data